# How to add a border around a canvas?

Tags: css, canvas, border

I want to now how you can add a border **around** a canvas. So simply with the CSS code

```
border:black 3px solid;
```

you get the border **in** the canvas. And I dont want the border in the canvas. I want the border **around** the canvas. I want this with CSS.

Thanks for helping!

my css code:

```
#my_canvas {
    max-width: 98%;
    max-height: 98%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:white;
    border:black 3px solid;
}
#center {
    max-width: 66.5%;
    max-height: 95%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin:auto;
    background:;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
Body {
    background-color: slategrey;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/r3ka2sj4/

Comment: I can't replicate this in Chrome. Border is definitely on the outside of the `canvas` element. Are you setting `box-sizing` to `border-box` anywhere, per chance?

Comment: if you use that thing --> nth-of-type(1) it works yea!! thanks

Comment: @Thomas All that is doing is selecting the canvas they wanted, nothing more. Your code works without it. [Your code working...](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/mso0Lx4v/) Also true, what browser are you using as it works in Chrome.

Comment: omg but without it doenst work for me... I use chrome

Comment: @Thomas Are you using `#my_canvas` more than once on the same page? Also in the Fiddle I put up thats your code working, so it does work.

Comment: yea sorry my fault.. It works now, I don`t know why but it works now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
outline: black 3px solid;
```

Outline will draw a line outside the element.

Answer (score 1):

may  i suggest this:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  #canvas{
border:2px solid black !important;}
```

Comment: How does this work, is this the html code? For me it just prints `#canvas{
border:2px solid black !important;}` as text...

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the canvas inheriting `box-sizing: border-box;`

Try applying `box-sizing: padding-box;` to the canvas CSS.

Comment: I gave my css code, do I need box-sixing and padding-box??

Comment: @Thomas You would need to add `box-sizing: padding-box;` to `#my_canvas` but this is only providing the issue is caused by a stray box-sizing property elsewhere.